# ember: Model can't extend another model for polymorphic association

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to get polymorphic associations to work but had no luck so far. Basically I wanted the track to belong to playlist AND album

```
App.Playlist = App.Trackable.extend

App.Album = App.Trackable.extend

App.Trackable = DS.Model.extend
  tracks: DS.hasMany 'track'

App.Track = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr 'string'
  trackable: DS.belongsTo('trackable',
    polymorphic: true)
```

But then I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the order wrong. You're trying to extend models that you have not declared yet. Try this:

```
App.Trackable = DS.Model.extend
  tracks: DS.hasMany 'track'

App.Playlist = App.Trackable.extend

App.Album = App.Trackable.extend

App.Track = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr 'string'
  trackable: DS.belongsTo('trackable',
    polymorphic: true)
```

Comment: Well actually they all have their seperate files since I tried to follow the ember folder structure :)

Comment: I see. Can you check that they are included in the right order? I think by default it will be done alphabetically, which will put `App.Playlist` before `App.Trackable`(assuming you named them accordingly)

Comment: I simply required the trackable file in my app.js before the other models and it worked :) Thanks!